# what to do with "Building workspace has encountered a problem"

Tags: java, eclipse

When i start Eclipse or do anything(like creating a package or a class) it always sends me this error :

"Building workspace" has encountered a problem

Details:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'learning'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: From the _Eclipse_ menu: **Window > Show View > Error Log** and also **Window > Show View > Problems**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide us more information about the error, using Abra comment, and try to search for clues. If it wont help, someone here could help.

Comment: Alternatively look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to your "Markers"-Tab and check for problems. In my case:
"The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 11 is used"

2) go into your ".log" file and check for detailed error messages

- the **.log**-File you will find in in your -Folder, inside the ".metadata"-Folder

In my case I saw this error message:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-09-10 18:30:28.624
!MESSAGE C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc.probe-b4958459-0f11-46f4-bc0f-85bf6a8174c1
!STACK 0

**Solution**:
I updated my eGit Plugin. Of course you can also uninstall it.
Go to the menu under "Help" -> "Eclipse Marketplace", then to the "Installed"-Tab

- Here you either update or uninstall the plugin that causes the problem